# why when my action returns a view - it passes first through a javascript function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

In the `Index` view I just have a button with a javascript function for when it's clicked:

```
<script>
    function AddCat() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("AddCategory")',
            data: {},
        });
    }
</script>

@Html.DropDownList("Languages", new SelectList(Model.lstLanguages, "LanguageID", "Name", Session["langID"] ?? "1"), new { id = "ddlLanguages" })
<div id="categoriesPlace"></div>
<input type="button" id="btnAddCategory" onclick="AddCat()" value="AddCategory" />
```

When I click on the button, as you see I should be redirected to the `AddCategory` action, which adds a record in the database and returns the  `AddCategory` view.  The problem is that when it reaches the drop-down in my `AddCategory` view, it goes straight to the `Addbtn_CLick()` function as if it's clicked and then it redirects me to the `Index` action. Can you explain this behavior?

So, here is my `CategoryController`:

```
public class CategoryController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult AddCategory()
    {
        CategoryViewModel vm = new CategoryViewModel();
        vm.AddNewCategory();
        return View(vm);
    }

    public ActionResult AddCategoriesLanguages(int catID, int lanID, string title, string shrtDescription, string description)
    {
        CategoryViewModel vm = new CategoryViewModel();
        vm.AddCategoriesLanguages(catID, lanID, title, shrtDescription, description);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");

    }
}
```

And, here is my `AddCategory` view:

```
@model Onion.Web.ViewModels.CategoryViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "AddCategory";
}


<h2>AddCategory</h2>
@Html.DropDownList("Languages", new SelectList(Model.lstLanguages, "LanguageID", "Name",@HttpContext.Current.Session["langID"]),new { id = "ddlLanguages" })
<br />
<label for="txbTitle">Title:</label>
<input type="text"  id="txbTitle"/>
 <br />
<label for="txbShortDescription">Short Description:</label>
<input type="text"  id="txbShortDescription" />
 <br />
 <br />
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" onclick="btnAdd_Click" value="Add" />

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>


<script>
    function btnAdd_Click() {    
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: '@Url.Action("AddCategoriesLanguages")' + '?catID=' +@Model.newCategoryID +'&lanID=' + $("#ddlLanguages").val() + '&title=' + $('#txbTitle').val() + '&shrtDescription=' + $('#txbShortDescription').val() + '&Description=' + $('#txbDescription').val(),
            data: {}
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by: 'when it reaches the dropdown' ?

Answer (score 0):

In your AddCategory view, try changing your button's onclick attribute to include the function name and parenthesis as shown below:

```
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" onclick="btnAdd_Click()" value="Add" />
```

I am not 100% sure if that is the issue, but it stood out to me.